# Is there a way to open playstore within an android app? And not deeplink and background the app?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I work on an android app and we use a lot of app install ads. Is there a way to open playstore within the app, without deeplinking to playstore and backgrounding my app?

Comment: Do you want to go to playstore by click on something in your app?

Comment: Yeah I wanna open a play store dialog or a model when the user taps on an app install ad, instead of going to the playstore.